# Flutter syncfusion pdf "Error: Invalid argument (The character is not supported by the font.)

Tags: flutter, pdf, syncfusion

I am developing a web application with Flutter. I also use the syncfusion_flutter_pdf package in my project. I can create a pdf file successfully in my project. However, I have to use Turkish characters in my project. For example, when I try to print the letters "ş,ğ,ı", I get an error like "Error: Invalid argument (The character is not supported by the font.): 319". How can I fix this problem?

Entering the characters "ş,ı,ğ" without any errors while creating the PDF file.

My code;

```
Future<void> generateInvoice() async {
    //Create a PDF document.
    final PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();
    //Add page to the PDF
    final PdfPage page = document.pages.add();
    //Get page client size
    final Size pageSize = page.getClientSize();


    //Draw rectangle
    page.graphics.drawRectangle(
        bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height),
        pen: PdfPen(PdfColor(142, 170, 219)));
    //Generate PDF grid.
    //Draw the header section by creating text element
    final PdfLayoutResult result = drawHeader(page, pageSize);
 
    final List<int> bytes = document.saveSync();
    //Dispose the document.
    document.dispose();
    //Save and launch the file.
    await saveAndLaunchFile(bytes, 'Invoice.pdf');
  }

  //Draws the invoice header
  PdfLayoutResult drawHeader(PdfPage page, Size pageSize) {
    //Draw rectangle
    page.graphics.drawRectangle(
        brush: PdfSolidBrush(PdfColor(91, 126, 215)),
        bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, pageSize.width - 115, 90));
    //Draw string
    page.graphics.drawString(
        'iş planı', PdfStandardFont(PdfFontFamily.helvetica, 30),
        brush: PdfBrushes.white,
        bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(25, 0, pageSize.width - 115, 90),
        format: PdfStringFormat(lineAlignment: PdfVerticalAlignment.middle));


  }
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To display Turkish characters on a PDF page, it is necessary to utilize a suitable font that supports the language's specific characters.

Use the following modified code with the supported font.

```
 //Create a True type font. The fontData is in bytes (unsigned 8-bit integer).
 PdfTrueTypeFont font = PdfTrueTypeFont(fontData, 14);
//Draw string
page.graphics.drawString(
   'is plani', font,
   brush: PdfBrushes.white,
   bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(25, 0, pageSize.width - 115, 90),
   format: PdfStringFormat(lineAlignment: PdfVerticalAlignment.middle));
```

Refer to the following UG documentation for further details.
https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/pdf/working-with-text#draw-text-using-truetype-fonts

Refer to the following KB article for further references, https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10447/how-to-create-a-pdf-file-in-flutter-web-platform
https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10391/how-to-read-pdf-file-in-syncfusion-flutter-pdf-library
https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/10420/how-to-draw-unicode-text-in-a-pdf-file-using-google-fonts-package-in-flutter